# error syntax mysql..when save array to database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I write code to save foreach data to the database.

foreach data is arrays .

For this reason firs convert array to string and then save to the database     but display following error on firefox.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'change,lowest,topest) VALUES ('[{"Name":"س\u06a9ه بها\u' at line 1
>   my code

```
$con = @mysql_connect ("localhost","root", "");
            mysql_select_db("coin", $con);
 if (!$con)
            {
 die(mysql_error());
 }else {
 foreach($table_rows as $tr) { // foreach row
 $row = $tr->childNodes;
if($row->item(0)->tagName != 'tblhead') { // avoid headers
    $data[] = array(
        'Name' =>trim($row->item(0)->nodeValue),
        'LivePrice' => trim($row->item(2)->nodeValue),
        'Change'=> trim($row->item(4)->nodeValue),
        'Lowest'=> trim($row->item(6)->nodeValue),
        'Topest'=> trim($row->item(8)->nodeValue),
        ///'Time'=> trim($row->item(10)->nodeValue),
    );
       }
  }

       $newstring = json_encode($data);

 $date=array();
 mysql_select_db ( "coin", $con );
  "CREATE TABLE `Dadoo`(id INT NOT NULL AUTO INCREMENT,name      VARCHAR(255),liveprice VARCHAR(255),change VARCHAR(255),lowest     VARCHAR(255),topest VARCHAR(255),PRIMARY KEY(id)) ENGINE=MyISAM" or die(mysql_error());
     $debugquery = mysql_query("INSERT INTO          `Dadoo`(name,liveprice,change,lowest,topest) VALUES ('$newstring')");
            if (!$debugquery)
        {
   die(mysql_error());
   }
     }
    mysql_close();
```

How fix it?

Comment: You cant insert a single string, JSON or not, in 5 different columns.

Answer (score 0):

`change` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) and needs to be escaped with backticks.

```
INSERT INTO `Dadoo`(name,liveprice,`change`,lowest,topest) ...
```

Comment: thanks, Now receiving error /// Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: That means that you tell the DB for instance you want to insert in 2 columns but provide only values for 1. Error producing Example: `insert into table (col1, col2) ('value')` There you are missing the value for `col2`

Comment: Now I do not know where is problem in my code // database field value is $newstring .. this variable was array.. I converted to string with json_encode .. then provide value for INSERT INTO `Dadoo`(name,liveprice,`change`,lowest,topest) VALUES ('$newstring')// I have only one value $newstring ..// where is problem?

Comment: The problem is that you have only one value for multiple columns. Split the variable.